# unclosable application Without Process

Tags: c#, shell-extensions

First excuse my for my bad English language
i'm Writing a security application for my company and i want to prevent users from opening specific program like torrent in my application. but this is not the problem. the problem begin where users can close my application some how....
they can end process and ...
i need some solution to Hide my application from users or make it Unclosable
i was thinking to something like Network Notify icon or Clock in windows, i read about Explorer extensions but they don't help me because they already Closable
by the way i need application start working on computer start-up Automatically
thanks Everybody

Comment: Run the application as Administrator (or some other user they don't have access to). Then they should need privileges to end the process which they can't acquire.

Comment: Sounds like a rootkit for me... Can't you just block torrent traffic in your companys router?

Comment: users are not managed... some of them are already administrator and they don't want to make application related to windows users

Comment: Torrent is sample. application should do some other works like global hook handling and do some work in some situation...

Answer (score 0):

Execute your watcher as a windows service and provider a user gui that only give some visual feedback to the user from the service by using some kind of inter-process communication. If the user closes the gui, the service still runs in the background.

But if your users have local administrator rights they can always stop your program (or service) somehow, otherwise they wouldn't be administrators of the system anymore.

Comment: Yes...
As you said they can stop windows service or end windows service process. additionally in windows vista and later isolation of session 0 made the works harder because interacting desktop from windows service is not so simple.

Comment: Already before Vista you should never let a service directly interact with a gui and instead used IPC. Due to the session 0 share it was possible, but it led to ugly bugs, if you used fast user switching or remote desktops (cause these already won't be started in session 0 under XP).